# Is there a way to construct and store a 3D Map from point cloud and depth data?

Tags: c++, 3d, kinect, point-cloud-library, slam-algorithm

I am currently working on a SLAM algorithm, and I succeeded in gathering the depth and RGB data on the form of a point cloud. However, I only display the frames that my Kinect 2.0 received to the screen and that is all.

I would like to gather those frames and as I move the Kinect, I construct a more elaborate Map (either 2D or 3D) so that it will help me in the localization or mapping.

My idea of the map construction would be just like when we create a Panorama image from many single snapshots.

Anyone has a clue, idea or an algorithm to do it?

Comment: Sounds like Kinect Fusion, which is part of the Kinect SDK. There are also open source implementations, e.g. as part of PCL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [rtabmap](http://introlab.github.io/rtabmap/) to create 3D map and localizing your device. Its very simple to use and supports different devices.